# Integration API Gateway with SQS without lambda

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

Is It possible repass client header to sqs with API Gateway without lambda?

For example:

In Mapping templates -> Generate templates I access the body with `$input.json('$')`.
I'm trying access
`Action=SendMessage&MessageBody={"body": $util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$')), "header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params('header')"}`
to repass header but it doesn't working because the header always comes empty.

Does Anybody knows how can I resolve this problem without lambda?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem changing the mapping templates to:

```
{
    "method": "$context.httpMethod",
    "body" : $input.json('$'),
    "headers": {
        #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
        "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
    }
}
```